# Android Studio is clearing logcat automatically after some crashes

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat

my Android Studio is clearing logcat automatically after some crashes which prevents me from debugging, any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Edit Filter Configuration -> Add your package name

And select NO FILTERS if you want te retrieve informations, even when the app is not running. Nothing is lost ;)